# 3js cube camera breaks after loading glb model

Tags: three.js, gltf

Im currenty working on a interior scene where create an interior from a floor plan, after its done loading I make a cube camera render of my scene and convert it to a equirectangular image.

When I add certain glb models the camera breaks with some sides being black and other not in the right place.

[broken panorama](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7YYh.png)
You can open it here: [360 viewer](https://renderstuff.com/tools/360-panorama-web-viewer/)

This is my code for taking the images:
`
createPanoramaFromPosition(positions: THREE.Vector3[], resolution: number) {

```
    // Create a cube camera to capture the panorama
    const cubeRenderTarget = new THREE.WebGLCubeRenderTarget(resolution * 2, {
      generateMipmaps: true,
      colorSpace: "srgb"
    });
    const cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera(0.1, 1000, cubeRenderTarget);
    cubeCamera.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
    this.scene.add(cubeCamera);

    // Call cubemapToEquirectangular to create the converter - sets renderer size
    const converter = this.cubemapToEquirectangular(resolution);
    const title = document.title;

    // Array to store panorama data URLs
    const panoramaDataUrls: { fileName: string, dataUrl: string }[] = [];

    // Capture the equirectangular images
    for (let position of positions) {
      const fileName = 'panorama-' + title + '-' + position.x + '_' + position.y + '.png';
      position.z = 1.5; // set to normal height
      cubeCamera.position.copy(position);
      const panoramaDataURL = converter.makePanorama(cubeCamera, this.scene);
      panoramaDataUrls.push({ fileName, dataUrl: panoramaDataURL });
    }

    // Save the images outside the loop
    for (let { fileName, dataUrl } of panoramaDataUrls) {
      this.saveImage(dataUrl, fileName);
    }

  }

  makePanorama(cubeCam: THREE.CubeCamera, providedScene: any) {
      console.time("makePanorama");
      planeRenderer.autoClear = true;
      cubeCam.update(planeRenderer, providedScene);
      planeRenderer.autoClear = autoClear;
      cubeCam.renderTarget.texture.generateMipmaps = true;
      quad.material.uniforms['map'].value = cubeCam.renderTarget.texture; // map the cubemap to the quad (equirectangular texture)
      planeRenderer.render(scene2, camera); // render it with orthographic camera
      console.timeEnd("makePanorama");
      return planeRenderer.domElement.toDataURL(); // return img data
    }
```

`

Is there a better way to take 360 images in 3js in general or is there a problem with my code?

I tried importing other glb models and most work but the ones i need don't.